# How to replace dataframe column values with NaN based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, the dataframe looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 1], [2, 120], [3, 25], [4, np.NaN], [5, 45]],
    columns=["ID", "Age"])
```

In the Age column, the values below 5 and greater than 100 have to convert to NaN.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying out the same with replace function, DF["Age"].replace(to_replace=DF["Age"]<5, value=np.NaN)
Is that not possible to do with replace ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df['Age'] = df.Age.where(df.Age.between(5, 100))
df
   ID   Age
0   1   NaN
1   2   NaN
2   3  25.0
3   4   NaN
4   5  45.0
```

Another option using `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df.Age.between(5, 100), 'Age'] = np.nan
```