# Replace a row in Pandas DataFrame with 'NaN' based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a Pandas DataFrame called `df` (378000, 82) and I would like to replace the entire row with `NaN` based on a specific condition. The condition is for any value in the column `df.halon_gas` that is >20, I want to replace that entire row with `NaN`. This is the way I want to filter my data so I don't lose the index values.

Thanks!

Comment: ¿Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983563/how-to-replace-a-dataframe-column-values-with-nan-based-on-a-condition] does this work for you?

Comment: @liamsuma it's close to what I want. For my DF, I want to replace the entire row (not just the one element in the column) so from column 0 to column 82 all get replaced with ```NaN``` because the ```df.halon_gas > 20```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all get all indexes of values, that are below 20

```
    idx = df[df.halon_gas >= 20].index
```

Then set the values for all columns and all columns which are below 200 to None

```
    df.set_value(idx, df.columns , None)
```

This should write None/Nan in the rows with the value below 20

Comment: I tried this and it worked BUT I had to switch your first line to read ```idx = df[df.halon_gas >= 20].index``` in order to get the values larger than 20 and replace the rows with ```NaN```

Comment: ah sorry I fix it :)

Comment: `set_value` is deprecated since version 0.21.0: Use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with the rows being gone then I suggest you do this:

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df = df[df.halon_gas <= 20]
df.set_index("index", inplace=True)
```

Whats happening here is the following:

1. The Index gets reset so you have an extra Column with the Index Values pre Removal.
2. Only the rows where df.halon_gas <= 20 are kept.
3. The old Index values are set to be the Index for the DataFrame again.

Comment: Ahh, so this WOULD work but I forgot to mention that many of the values in my ```df.halon_gas``` column are ```NaN``` so when I filter, the filter tosses out those values too but I need to keep those elements. Thank you for adding explanation to your answer!